# $httpBackend.whenGET(some url).passThrough() throws exception?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some problem here. I am trying to mock some of my http request to the server and pass some of them through ! When I call passThrougth() an Error is thrown !

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET view/networks.html
No more request expected
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at $httpBackend (http://localhost:8080/js/lib/angular-mocks.js:887:9)
    at $httpBackend (http://localhost:8080/js/lib/angular-mocks.js:880:11)
    at sendReq (http://localhost:8080/js/lib/angular-scenario.js:18264:9)
    at $http (http://localhost:8080/js/lib/angular-scenario.js:18055:17)
    at Function.$get.$http.(anonymous function) [as get] (http://localhost:8080/js/lib/angular-scenario.js:18198:18)
    at $get.$q.when.then.then.next.locals (http://localhost:8080/js/lib/angular-scenario.js:16605:34)
    at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (http://localhost:8080/js/lib/angular-scenario.js:16028:59)
    at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (http://localhost:8080/js/lib/angular-scenario.js:16028:59)
    at ref.then (http://localhost:8080/js/lib/angular-scenario.js:16065:26)
```

here is my run

```
myAppDev.run(function ($httpBackend) {
    $httpBackend.whenGET("view/networks.html").passThrough();
    $httpBackend.whenGET('/r/networkInterface').respond(networkInterfaces);

});
```

What is the problem with my config ?

Any way, When I call response(" with some response "), I get results right. i.e the $httpBackEnd returns what is put in response !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys, after a long and hard fight the problem was very simple to solve.

1- Update to angularJS 1.0.5

2- in my tests I had this line of code

```
myAppDev.config(function ($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$httpBackend', angular.mock.e2e.$httpBackendDecorator);
});
```

When I removed this line of code everything went perfect. However, this is what Vojta jina used [in this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/DQHdk/)